# How to set value of button(created in js) to a hidden value (set inside a html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is required - We need to set the button text which is created dynamically inside sample.js to a text which we have set in a hidden field in sample.html
Piece of html is - 
sample.html

```
<div type="hidden" id="readfromhere" value="OK"></div>
```

Piece of JS logic is -sample.js

```
$('#id').append("<div><a id="buttontext"></a></div>")
$('#buttontext').val($('#readfromhere').val());
```

This is not working , can anyone suggest where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you use `<div>` element instead of `<input>`?

Comment: `a` and `div` elements don't have a `value` attributes - why are you attempting to add/read them? It would be better if you could describe why you need this, as your code is flawed for a variety of reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

buttontext is an **anchor** tag, use `text/html` instead of `val` and the element of hidden type should be `input` and not `div`. `div` elements don't have a `value` and `type` attributes

```js
$('#id').append("<div><a id='buttontext'></a></div>")
$('#buttontext').text($('#readfromhere').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="readfromhere" value="OK">
<div id="id"></div>
```

Comment: Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

`buttontext` is an **anchor tag**, use `html` instead of `val`

```
$('#buttontext').html($('#readfromhere').attr( "value" ));
```

**Note**

- Also note that `readfromhere` is a `div` tag, so read attribute `value`